# Php и лимит оперативной памяти.

Tags: memory, php, ubuntu

У меня довольно ресурсоемкая задача, а именно парсинг xml и обработка в цикле. В цикле на заход 4-5 запросов + возможно сохранение картинки с последующим добавлением в БД.
Так вот, это все съедает память, и может на 7000 итерации заглохнуть, хотя оперативы 512Мб, в php лимит 456Мб. 
Запросы не большие, можно попытаться уменьшить количество, но намного лучше от этого не станет, верно?
Как можно снизить процент вылетов? Поможет ли sleep() снизить нагрузку?

Comment: @MrGaliev, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: в некоторых случаях можно использовать SAX или StAX парсер вместо DOM. Сильно экономит память.

Answer (score 3):

> Как можно снизить процент вылетов?

Совершать одну операцию за раз, подчищая после нее память (unset всему отработанному). Скорее всего, там копится некий лог операций, который достаточно радувается к определенному моменту, его и надо выкидывать. XML тоже надо обрабатывать по одной конструкции за раз.

> Запросы не большие, можно попытаться уменьшить количество, но намного лучше от этого не станет, верно?

Верно, это повлияет на сервак БД, но не на скрипт PHP.

> У меня довольно ресурсоемкая задача, а именно парсинг xml и обработка в цикле.

да не особо.

> Поможет ли sleep() снизить нагрузку?

нет.